# Regex match until "&" or "|"

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

I have the following string `[Field1]='Field1Value'|[Field2]='Field2Value'&[Field3]='Field3Value'` and I want to get a regular expression match until either `"&"` or `"|"` but I also want to include the `"&"` or `"|"` in my matches.

Meaning my string should create the following matches:

```
1. [Field1]='Field1Value'
2. | 
3. [Field2]='Field2Value' 
4. &
5. [Field3]='Field3Value'
```

I am using `([^&^\|]*)` right now but the problem is this returns:

```
1. [Field1]='Field1Value'
2. '' 
3. [Field2]='Field2Value' 
4. ''
5. [Field3]='Field3Value'
6. ''
```

Comment: A word of warning: if you're going to parse this string, regular expressions is not the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below code.

```
> var s = "[Field1]='Field1Value'|[Field2]='Field2Value'&[Field3]='Field3Value'";
undefined
> s.match(/[^|&]+|[|&]/g)
[ '[Field1]=\'Field1Value\'',
  '|',
  '[Field2]=\'Field2Value\'',
  '&',
  '[Field3]=\'Field3Value\'' ]
```

**Explanation:**

- `[^|&]+` Match any character but not of `|` or `&` one or more times.
- `|` OR
- `[|&]` Match `|` or `&` symbols.

Answer (score 0):

`Split` can return the separator when using parenthesis :

```
var s = "[Field1]='Field1Value'|[Field2]='Field2Value'&";
s.split(/(\&|\|)/g);
/*
    ==> [
        "[Field1]='Field1Value'",
        "|",
        "[Field2]='Field2Value'",
        "&",
        ""
    ]
*/
```